# Invariance of the Schoedinger equation for the Galilean transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

Show that the schroedinger e is covariant under the galilean transformation :
$\overrightarrow{r'}=\overrightarrow{r}-\overrightarrow{V}t$
iff the wave fucntion transforms like:
$$\psi^\prime=e^{\left(\frac{-i}{\hbar}m\overrightarrow{V}\cdot\overrightarrow{r}+\frac{i}{2\hbar}mv^2t\right)}\psi$$ 
  where $v$ is the potential.

I think the way out of this problem is to explore the property that the partial differentiation of the $\psi$ by $t'$ gives some new term that excludes with the laplacian terms, by honestly i can't go further.

$$i\hbar\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi+v\psi$$

Comment: Do you know anything about the chain rule of differentiation?

Comment: yes, but i am a little confused with the different time dependences of the wave functions

Comment: The Schrödinger equation is not invariant under Galilei boosts. Who gave you this problem?